# Extract certain part from a string in R

Tags: r, string, extract

I would like to extract a part of the string. Here is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2),
                 string = c('<itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_2</value>',
                            '<itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_4</value>'))

> df
  id                                                                       string
1  1 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_2</value>
2  2 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_4</value>
```

I would like to extract `ETC_CHOICE_2` and `ETC_CHOICE_4` from the long string. My desired output would be:

```
> df
  id                                                                       string  extract
1  1 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_2</value>  ETC_CHOICE_2
2  2 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_4</value>  ETC_CHOICE_4
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `htmlParse` from `XML`

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(extract = htmlParse(string) %>%
                    getNodeSet("//value") %>%
                    xmlValue)
```

-output

```
#id                                                                       string      extract
#1  1 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_2</value> ETC_CHOICE_2
#2  2 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_4</value> ETC_CHOICE_4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract everything between `<value>` and `</value>`.

```
df$extract <- sub('.*<value>(.*)</value>', '\\1', df$string)
df

#  id                                                                       string      extract
#1  1 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_2</value> ETC_CHOICE_2
#2  2 <itemResponse><response id="editIn_1.RESPONSE_1"><value>ETC_CHOICE_4</value> ETC_CHOICE_4
```

Comment: I appreciate your time. THis solution indeed can be used in different ways since you proposed the location of the desired extracted part. Thanks!